# Clojure partition-by: group some elements and leave other as is

Tags: clojure

Is there an idiomatic way to go from here:

```
[{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 4} {:red 5} {:blue 6} {:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}]
```

to here:

```
 [[{:red 1} {:red 2}] 
  [{:blue 3}] 
  [{:blue 4}] 
  [{:red 5}] 
  [{:blue 6}] 
  [{:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}]]
```

i.e. any consecutive reds are grouped together, but each blue is kept as a separate group?

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification:

1. Consecutive blues can have the same values. 
2. In real life it is more like red, blue, green, and so on, but only reds should be grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `partition-by` to group consecutive values in a sequence:

```clj
(partition-by ffirst [{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 4} {:red 5} {:blue 6} {:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}])
;; => (({:red 1} {:red 2})
;;     ({:blue 3} {:blue 4})
;;     ({:red 5})
;;     ({:blue 6})
;;     ({:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}))
```

I see that in your case you want to group only `:red` keys. So we can construct specific function for that:

```clj
(partition-by #(or (contains? % :red) %) 
              [{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 4} {:red 5} {:blue 6} {:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}])
;; => (({:red 1} {:red 2})
;;     ({:blue 3})
;;     ({:blue 4})
;;     ({:red 5})
;;     ({:blue 6})
;;     ({:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}))
```

Comment: Your approach relies on consecutive `:blue` maps having different values, which works in this specific case, but doesn't generalize well, e.g. for a collection like `[{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 3}]`.

Comment: That's true. `rand` is also risky. I believe this is a toy example and author will be able to create proper grouping function for real case. The point is to use `partition-by` function.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple approach:

```
(def x [{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 4} {:red 5} {:blue 6} {:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}])

(partition-by #(if (:red %) :const (rand)) x)

;; =>(({:red 1} {:red 2})
;;   ({:blue 3})
;;   ({:blue 4})
;;   ({:red 5})
;;   ({:blue 6})
;;   ({:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}))
```

What `partition-by` does is run a function on every element of a collection, splitting it when we get a different value. In this case, we need to construct a custom function that branches on whether a map's key is `:red` or something else (e.g. `:blue`), always returning the same thing for `:red` (e.g. a constant like the keyword `:const`), but returning a different thing all the time for other keys like `:blue` (which can be done with a random function like `rand`).

The anonymous function we gave it, `#(if (:red %) :const (rand))` does just that - checks if the key is `:red`, then issues a branched return value based on that.

However, as @cfrick mentioned in a comment, there's the worry of getting the same random number twice in a row - extremely unlikely, but still a worry. If the use of `rand` leaves you feeling slightly dissatisfied, below is an alternative using the current time (down to nanoseconds) instead of a random number, which is guaranteed to always yield a different result in a sequential process:

```
(partition-by #(if (:red %) :const (java.time.LocalDateTime/now)) x)
```

Comment: Very optimistic, that rand will not give the same value twice.  https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @cfrick Good point :) Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the underlying Java `Math.random()` method further relies on the `Random` class, which is linear deterministic and prevents the same random number showing up twice in a row...

Comment: I have never checked that - but i'd not rely on that.  Of course this is a corner case.

Comment: @cfrick Fair enough - better to be safe than sorry! I updated my answer to also present another similar approach, using the current time instead of `rand`. Thoughts?

Comment: The partitioning function could also be `#(if (:red %) :const (gensym))` or `(let [a (atom 0)] #(when-not (:red %) (swap! a inc) @a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit clumsy to do work first and then partially undo it, but it
is at least relative safe on the border cases (same values for `:blue`)
and actually keeping any non-red apart.

```
user=> (sequence 
         (comp 
           (partition-by #(contains? % :red)) 
           (mapcat #(if (-> % first (contains? :red)) 
                      [%] 
                (map vector %)))) 
         [{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 3} {:red 5}])
([{:red 1} {:red 2}] 
 [{:blue 3}] 
 [{:blue 3}] 
 [{:red 5}])
```

Answer (score 0):

i would go with something like this:

```
(let [is-red? #(contains? % :red)]
  (transduce (comp (partition-by is-red?)                   
                 (map #(if (is-red? (first %)) [%] (map vector %))))
             into [] data))
;; [[{:red 1} {:red 2}]
;;  [{:blue 3}]
;;  [{:blue 4}]
;;  [{:red 5}]
;;  [{:blue 6}]
;;  [{:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}]]
```

another one is to introduce some synthetic key for `blue` data, in this case `index` would be ok:

```
(->> data
     (map-indexed (fn [idx itm] {:key (or (contains? itm :red) idx)
                                 :itm itm}))
     (partition-by :key)
     (map (partial map :itm)))

;; (({:red 1} {:red 2})
;;  ({:blue 3})
;;  ({:blue 4})
;;  ({:red 5})
;;  ({:blue 6})
;;  ({:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}))
```

you can also put the partition key to metadata, to avoid extra records creation:

```
(->> data
     (map-indexed (fn [idx itm]
                    (vary-meta itm assoc :part-key (or (contains? itm :red) idx))))
     (partition-by (comp :part-key meta)))

;; (({:red 1} {:red 2})
;;  ({:blue 3})
;;  ({:blue 4})
;;  ({:red 5})
;;  ({:blue 6})
;;  ({:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(reduce
 (fn [acc e]
   (if (and (:red e) (:red (peek (peek acc))))
     (update acc (dec (count acc)) conj e)
     (conj acc [e])))
 []
 [{:red 1} {:red 2} {:blue 3} {:blue 4} {:red 5} {:blue 6} {:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}])
;; => [[{:red 1} {:red 2}]
;;     [{:blue 3}]
;;     [{:blue 4}]
;;     [{:red 5}]
;;     [{:blue 6}]
;;     [{:red 7} {:red 8} {:red 9}]]
```